# Does the S3 reader in read_csv() download files to disk first or does it use streaming?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using `read_csv`in Pandas to read data from S3. I was wondering if it first downloads the file to local disk and then load in memory, or directly streams the incoming data into memory, without having an intermediate step of loading to disk.

I have the same question for Spark's `sqlContext.read.load` function.

Comment: Maybe you should ask another question for sqlContext.read.load, since Spark is a completely separate library from pandas.... I suspect you would be more likely to get an answer that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pandas uses boto](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/common.py#L290) for access to s3, which [does appear to stream](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html) file data.